# How to find Find all continuous functions f, g and h from R to R that satisfy $f(x + y) = g(x) + h(y)$ for all $x, y ∈ R$.

Tags: functions, contest-math

Find all continuous functions f, g and h from R to R that satisfy
$f(x + y) = g(x) + h(y)$ for all $x, y ∈ R$. This thing is a little bit like Homomorphism/Linear function so technically all linear function f can fulfill the requirement, I mean $f, f$, and $f$. But I guess there are other kinds.

Comment: They can be constant functions.

Comment: All these functions only differ by a constant.

Comment: $g(x)=f(x)-h(0)$ and $h(x)=f(x)-g(0)$

Comment: So, the condition reads, $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0)$

Comment: So $f(nx)=f((n-1)x)+f(x)-f(0)=f((n-2)x)+2f(x)-2f(0)=...=nf(x)-(n-1)f(0)$

Comment: $mf(\frac{x}{m})-mf(0)=f(x)-f(0)$ So, $f(\frac{x}{m})-f(0)=\frac{1}{m}(f(x)-f(0))$

Comment: So, $f(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{1}{q}(f(p)-f(0))+f(0)=\frac{1}{q}(pf(1)-(p-1)f(0)-f(0))+f(0)=\frac{p}{q}(f(1)-f(0))+f(0)$

Comment: Or, once you get to $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) - f(0)$, then $f(x) - f(0)$ satisfies the Cauchy functional equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments above. I can't copy for sone reason. In short, $g(x)=f(x)-h(0)$ and similarily for $h$. Convert the original equation to $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0)$ and then use induction to see $f(nx)=n((f(x)-f(0))+f(0)$ Then, we can also get $f(\frac{x}{m})=\frac{1}{m}(f(x)-f(0))+f(0)$ So now we have, $f(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{p}{q}(f(1)-f(0))+f(0)$. By continuity, you get, $f(x)=x(f(1)-f(0))+f(0)$. Thus, $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Put $y=-x$ to get $f(0)=g(x)+h(-x)$. So $g(x)=c-h(-x)$ where $c=f(0)$. Now $f(x+y)=c-h(-x)+h(y)$. Put $y=0$ to get $f(x)=c-h(-x)+h(0)$. Hence $h(y)=A-f(-y)$ for some constant $A$ and $g(x)=c-A+f(x)$. The original equation becomes $f(x+y)=c+f(x)-f(-y)$. Can you proceed? [Show that $f(x)-f(0)$ is additive].

[All the functions are of the type $ax+b$].